# Delete Rows with NOW() using time zone

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to run mysql query to delete rows, but facing a timezone problem. My server is in the US and my users are in Asia. The timestamp which is entered in table is Asian. Can I delete rows with asian time? Here is my query ;

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM SMS_IN WHERE NOW() > sent_dt");
```

`NOW()` is taking US time instead of Asian time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [CONVERT_TZ](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) to convert time from user time zone to server time zone:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), 'user time zone', 'server time zone');
```

For example:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM SMS_IN WHERE CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), 'Asia/Hong_Kong', 'America/Montreal') > sent_dt");
```

Comment: Thanks Ruben but little change in script works for me as mysql_query("DELETE FROM SMS_IN WHERE CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), 'America/Phoenix', 'Asia/Calcutta') > sent_dt"); as i my server is in us and user time zone is asian... any way thx bro

Answer (score 0):

You can either change the global `time_zone`, or you can use `DATE_ADD` or `DATE_SUB` on `NOW()` to adjust the number of hours of separation, which is probably known by you (and I hope for the sake of all of us will remain constant [except for DST]).